# How to rewrite ACPI control tables from Linux?

Tags: linux-mint, fan, linux-kernel, acpi

I have a HP Probook 4720s laptop with broken ACPI tables. The fan is always switched off and the computer tends to overheat and shut down. Under Windows I can use a program called RW_Everything to write values to the embedded controller of my computer to manually switch the fan back on (value: 0x40, offset: 0xD5). As I am migrating to Linux, I am looking for another way of writing these values to the memory of the embedded controller.

How can I do that in Linux (Mint)?

Answer (score 0):

I have been tinkering with this same thing and finally found some code online that does the job. Let me first warn you that messing with these registers is generally not a good idea. That aside, I created this GitHub repository for the purpose of detailing the process. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

http://github.com/RayfenWindspear/perl-acpi-fanspeed